# Number of users

Tags: api, foursquare

/venues/VENUE_ID/herenow endpoint helps us get information about user's count in venue. But is it possible to check, if really coords of user match venue coords? User could checkin one place from other place and latitude and longitude in /checkins/add endpoint is optional parameters. So can I check how many users checkin exactly from selected venue?

Comment: Could you try to explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this information is not available through Foursquare's API.  I suppose there are a couple of reasons for this:

1) Location data is easy to spoof, if you know the API you can say you are anywhere. So knowing the user's "real" location won't matter in the end because it can be faked.

2) GPS systems can put you way off from where you think you are, especially in cities.  So an accurate fix isn't possible sometimes.  Even if a user is really at the venue they are checking in at, their GPS coordinates will vary slightly from the venue's coordinates.

3) I believe Foursquare lets you just check in anywhere to avoid the headaches that Gowalla went through early on - a constant stream of people complaining they couldn't check in to places they were legitimately at because of a small checkin radius, combined with GPS problems outlined above.